# сравнение строк в одном файле в jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

У меня есть один `txt file` и он состоит из рядов (букв) и 30 столбцов, в которых стоят + и -.

Нужно, по введенной буквe проверить все ряды на определение самой похожей буквы.

```
буква   звонкость    губной звук ...
p         +              +    -    +    -   -
t         -              -    +    +    +   +
b         -              +    -    +    -   -
...

test_cases = ['f', 'ʈ','ð', '@']

import tcv

f=open("ipa2hayes.txt")

line=f.readline()

def voice(phone):

for phone in line:
  ......?

f.close()

print(voice("p"))
>> b
```

Comment: Учитесь карина. Как я понял из предыдущего вашего вопроса, вы вообще не понимаете ничего.

Comment: @KarinaNassyrova , в начале текста - это пример данных из файла? Строка с названиями колонок тоже присутствует в файле?

Comment: Для сравнения многомерных векторов можно воспользоваться “cosine similarity” или “cosine distance”. Для этого надо преобразовать данные из файла в числовую (бинарную) матрицу. В качестве индексов строк можно использовать буквы. Если использовать модули Pandas и SciKit-Learn то код получится достаточно компактным и относительно понятным.

Comment: @MaxU - прекрасный совет! ;-)